# Why does my addSeries (in highcharts) only display names of the series but not the actual pie chart itself

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When trying to add Series to a Highcharts piechart only the names of the series displays but not the graph itself.

If I input the series manually the chart displays correctly but when it's done via .each loop it only shows the added series names.

Here is my code:

```
function my_pie(){
        // Build the chart
   $('#pie_chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            marginBottom: 0,
            spacingTop: 0,
            marginTop:0,
            marginLeft:50,
            marginRight:50
        },
        credits:{
            enabled:false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Innehav',
            data: [ ] 
        }]
    });

    var chart = $('#pie_chart').highcharts();

    $.each(data_array, function( index, value ) {
        chart.addSeries({                        
            name: index,
            y: parseInt(value)
        }, false);
    });
    chart.redraw();
};
```

Here is the output from console.log(data_array)

```
Object {Ja: "272", Nej: "30", Vet ej: "1"}
```

Update:
Here is how the data_array is generated (I added num_check to make values integers)

```
var data_array = <?php echo json_encode($data_pie, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ) ?>;
```

And now the console.log(data_array) looks like this:

```
 Object {Ja: 272, Nej: 30, Vet ej: 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pie chart is just one series, not multiple ones like other types. You should be adding values instead:

```
$.each(data_array, function( index, value ) {
    chart.series[0].addPoint({                        
        name: index,
        y: parseInt(value)
    }, false);
});
chart.redraw();
```

Or better, use `setData`:

```
var data = []
$.each(data_array, function( index, value ) {
    data.push( [index, parseInt(value) ]);
});
chart.series[0].setData(data);
```